Displaying Tags In Category List Layout (Joomla 3 vs Joomla 5)
I am currently in the process upgrading a Joomla! 3 site to Joomla! 5, so far everything is working fine except a Category List template override I made (in Joomla! 3) that displays article tags along with the title and author.
In Joomla! 3 I was able to use this code:
    <td>
        <?php $this->item->tagLayout = new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->item->tagLayout->render($article->tags->itemTags); ?>
    </td>

But it seems as though this no longer works in Joomla! 5 as I am now getting this error:
Attempt to assign property "tagLayout" on null

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Please clarify which file you are editing.

@sharky this would be in a template override of the default_articles.php file (in: templates/my_template/html/com_content/category).

There is no $this->item property in this view. You can assign the layout instance to $article->tagLayout, a custom variable or not assign it at all:
<?php echo (new JLayoutFile('joomla.content.tags'))->render($article->tags->itemTags); ?>

Also, there is a shorthand JLayoutHelper::render() method that you can use instead:
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.tags', $article->tags->itemTags); ?>

Finally, J-prefixed classes are deprecated. You should use fully qualified class names. E.g. Joomla\CMS\Layout\LayoutHelper instead of JLayoutHelper.

Thank you so much @Sharky this worked perfectly! I also took your advice and it turns out you are right using the fully qualified class names also works in place of JLayoutHelper in J5 (using the inline code). I also tried adding Joomla\CMS\Layout\LayoutHelper with 'use' at the beginning of default_articles and calling it just with LayoutHelper which also seems to work in J5. I am not that good with php in general but I am assuming the last option is probably the best use case.
